# Есть ли преимущества в использовании числа вместо типа bool в Posgresql?

Tags: java, sql, postgresql

Несколько раз встречал в таблицах базы, относящейся к веб-приложению на Java, столбцы, играющие роль флага, но имеющие не привычный тип `bool`, а `smallint` который принимает значения `0` или `1` вместо `false` и `true` соответственно.

Какие преимущества такого способа? Интересуют соображения, как и в рамках работы БД, так и возможного влияния на архитектуру веб-приложения.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вопрос довольно обширный, и на него вряд ли можно ответить полностью.
Мой личный опыт говорит, что були часто имеют привычку становиться
перечислениями.  Сначала у вас просто `ON`
и `OFF`.  Потом подбегает манагер и говорит, что надо
различать неустановленный режим, и появляется `UNSET`.
С этим ещё можно справиться через `NULL`, но потом тот же
манагер добавляет вам режим по расписанию (`SCHEDULED`),
автоматический режим (`AUTO`), какой-нибудь режим клоуна,
и проч.  Поэтому многие при проработке архитектур и *API*
предпочитают вместо булей сразу иметь перечисления, в том числе
в качестве `INTEGER`ов в базе.